# Half my page is loading because of URL rewrite database error

Tags: database, magento-enterprise, magento-1, url-rewrite

This is really frustrating and I've been following all my error messages and fixing them until this last one... I'm not sure what this one means.

My error report message is saying:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:2940:"SELECT `e`.*, IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) AS `is_active`, IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) AS `include_in_menu`, IFNULL(url_rewrite.request_path, default_ur.request_path) AS `request_path` FROM `catalog_category_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active_default` ON (`at_is_active_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active_default`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND `at_is_active_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_is_active` ON (`at_is_active`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_is_active`.`attribute_id` = '42') AND (`at_is_active`.`store_id` = 1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu_default` ON (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu_default`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND `at_include_in_menu_default`.`store_id` = 0
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `at_include_in_menu` ON (`at_include_in_menu`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`attribute_id` = '67') AND (`at_include_in_menu`.`store_id` = 1)
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite_category` ON url_rewrite_category.category_id = e.entity_id AND url_rewrite_category.store_id = 1
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_url_rewrite` AS `url_rewrite` ON url_rewrite_category.url_rewrite_id = url_rewrite.url_rewrite_id AND url_rewrite.is_system = 1
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite` AS `default_urc` ON default_urc.category_id = e.entity_id AND default_urc.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `enterprise_url_rewrite` AS `default_ur` ON default_ur.url_rewrite_id = default_urc.url_rewrite_id AND default_ur.is_system = 1 WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '3') AND (`e`.`entity_id` IN('3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100', '101', '102', '103', '104', '105', '106', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119', '120', '121', '122', '123', '124', '125', '126', '127', '128', '129', '130', '131', '132', '133', '134', '135', '136', '137', '138', '139', '140', '141', '142', '143', '145')) AND (IF(at_is_active.value_id > 0, at_is_active.value, at_is_active_default.value) = '1') AND (IF(at_include_in_menu.value_id > 0, at_include_in_menu.value, at_include_in_menu_default.value) = '1')
";i:1;s:5945:"#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#5 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#6 lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(740): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, I...', Array)
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1047): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `e`.*, I...')
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(871): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Collection.php(225): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load(false, false)
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Tree.php(168): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection->load()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category.php(576): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree->addCollectionData(NULL, false, '2', true, true)
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php(818): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category->getCategories('2', 0, false, false, true)
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Category.php(82): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category->getCategories('2', 0, false, false, true)
#14 app/code/local/webs/Catalog/Model/Observer.php(13): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Category->getStoreCategories()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): webs_Catalog_Model_Observer->addCatalogToTopmenuItems(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(webs_Catalog_Model_Observer), 'addCatalogToTop...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#17 app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php(74): Mage::dispatchEvent('page_block_html...', Array)
#19 app/design/frontend/enterprise/webs/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(34): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->getHtml('level-top')
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('app/de...')
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#25 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#26 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', false)
#28 app/design/frontend/enterprise/webs/template/page/html/header.phtml(53): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu', false)
#29 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('app/de...')
#30 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#31 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#32 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#33 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#34 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#35 app/design/frontend/enterprise/webs/template/page/1column.phtml(41): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#36 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('app/de...')
#37 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/enterp...')
#38 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#39 app/code/local/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#40 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#41 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#42 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#43 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#44 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#45 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#46 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#47 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#48 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#49 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#50 index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#51 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Looks like there is a conflict inside one of the `url_rewrite` tables??

I tried to truncate them but still nothing.

**UPDATE:**

I ran the query and it said "*unknown table: `enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite`*"

So I built the table and now it's saying: "*Unknown column 'url_rewrite_category.category_id' in 'on clause'*"

Comment: To have a better idea, you could try to execute the query in your favorite database management tool. As long as you are on Enterprise Edition, you might contact Magento Support for a better answer.

Comment: I'll run the top mysql query, i thought about doing that but wasn't sure.

Comment: I ran the query and it said unknown table: enterprise_catalog_category_rewrite  <<< so i built the table and now it's saying: Unknown column 'url_rewrite_category.category_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @thismethod did you already find something?

Comment: @7ochem, yes i figured it out.

Comment: @thismethod could you post your solution as an answer here?